# Specifying a default Unity type mapping for a generic interface and class pair

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, automapper

We're using constructor-based dependency injection, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity) on a codebase.

We have wrapped AutoMapper with a generic interface...

```
public interface IMapper<TSource, TDestination>
{
    TDestination Map(TSource source);
}
```

And a class that implements this interface...

```
public class AutomaticMapper<TSource, TDestination> : IMapper<TSource, TDestination>
{
    public TDestination Map(TSource source)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

This works well, but it means that for every mapping we define in the AutoMapper configuration we need to perform an additional `UnityContainer.RegisterType`.

These type mappings are almost always of the form

```
container.RegisterType<IMapper<ClassA, ClassB>, AutomaticMapper<ClassA, ClassB>>();
```

Is there any way that we can tell unity to use a default type mapping that maps from `IMapper` to `AutomaticMapper` using the same `TSource` and `TDestination` for each of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We actually do almost the same exact thing. In Unity, you can say:

```
unityContainer.RegisterType(typeof(IMapper<,>), typeof(AutomaticMapper<,>));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AutomaticMapper : IMapper
{
    public TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an auto registration add-in  for Unity that probably does what you want.  Have a look at http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=59418