# Injecting a specific instance of an interface using Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper, autofac

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and Autofac for my dependency injection.  I am using AutoMapper for my mapping.

I have an IMapper class that I use for all my model view mappings.  So any any of my mapping classes can implement this interface.  In the controller below the constructor receives an IMapper instance, and in my User controller it might receive a different instance, maybe userMapper.  Getting back to the code below, I have a class called NewsMapper and it implements IMapper.  How do I setup dependency injection so that this controller must receive an instance of NewsMapper?  Please bear in mind that I might have another mapper called UserMapper.

I have the following controller:

```
public class NewsController
{
   private INewsService newsService;
   private IMapper newsMapper;

   public NewsController(INewsService newsService, IMapper newsMapper)
   {
      if (newsService == null)
      {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("newsService");
      }

      if (newsMapper == null)
      {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("newsMapper");
      }

      this.newsService = newsService;
      this.newsMapper = newsMapper;
   }
}
```

I have the following configuration in my global.asax.cs:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterType<NewsService>().As<INewsService>();
builder.RegisterType<NewsRepository>().As<INewsRepository>();
```

UPDATED:

My IMapper interface:

```
public interface IMapper
{
   object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
}
```

My NewsMapper class:

```
public class NewsMapper : IMapper
{
   static NewsMapper()
   {
      Mapper.CreateMap<News, NewsViewModel>();
      Mapper.CreateMap<NewsViewModel, News>();
   }

   public object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
   {
      return Mapper.Map(source, sourceType, destinationType);
   }
}
```

My controller action method where I do the mappings:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
{
   // Check model state
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View("Create", newsViewModel);
   }

   // Do mapping
   var news = (News)newsMapper.Map(newsViewModel, typeof(NewsViewModel), typeof(News));

   // Add to database via news service

   // Redirect to list view
   return RedirectToAction("List", "News");
}
```

Comment: Did you register your builder with the MVC system?

Comment: @BuildStarted: Yes everything is setup properly, I didn't include all my code, just part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the broadness of the `IMapper` contract. It is too general - the `NewsController` wants to map something like `News` to `NewsViewModel` but `IMapper` just says "maps something to something."

Instead, have a look at creating a generic variant such as `IMapper<TFrom,TTo>`. Then, you can set up container so that the `NewsController` receives an `IMapper<News,NewsModel>` which is unambiguous and should uniquely match the `NewsMapper` component (however you decide to set that up.)

**Edit**

For examples/variants on the generic mapper theme see:

- http://consultingblogs.emc.com/owainwragg/archive/2010/12/15/automapper-profiles.aspx
- http://lucisferre.net/2009/12/31/graphite-update-the-automapfilter-for-model-e280933e-viewmodel-mapping/
- [Specifying a default Unity type mapping for a generic interface and class pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198982/specifying-a-default-unity-type-mapping-for-a-generic-interface-and-class-pair)

Comment: @Nick: I don't understand your answer 100%. I have updated my original post to show you how I am implementing my mappings.  How would change it to suite your explanation?  Would you mind including sample code in your answer?  Just another question, should mapping be included in the controller, or in the service layer?

Comment: @Brendan I'm usually skeptical of AutoMapper usage in this context - if you're burdened with having to maintain e.g. a serialisable representation of a domain model then it is useful, but in this case I'd make the controller responsible for managing its view models (and probably just aggregate domain objects into them where possible.)